# Getting all twitter followers id with Parse (cloud code)

Tags: twitter, parse-platform

Using twitter API from Parse cloud code, I can obtain 5000 followers / request. 
With a user auth, I can make 15 requests / 15 minutes.

If a user has more than 75K followers, I should then execute the job again with a 15 min delay. However, it is not possible to execute delayed jobs in Parse.

One solution seems to create database entries for on-going jobs, with the twitter Id, and the number of followers already retrieved. And to create a task running every 15 minutes to action these jobs.

But it seems a lot of pain for something very natural : getting the followers of a user signed up with twitter.

Am I missing something ?

Comment: What are you getting them for?

Comment: I want to know if some of the followers of the newly sign up user are already on the app